# How to apply Scroll VIew to Box Layout in kivy

Tags: android, python, scroll, kivy

I have lots of Button and I want to apply scrollview to Box Layout like below

```
<My Class>:
  ScrollView:
    BoxLayout:
      Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       Button:
        text:"buttone1"
       GridLayout:
         rows:4
         cols:4
         Button:
           text:"buttone1"
         Button:
           text:"buttone1"
         Button:
           text:"buttone1"
         Button:
           text:"buttone1"
         Button:
           text:"buttone1"
```

how can i Apply Scrollview to above Content

Answer (score 1):

put all the buttons and textviews inside a SINGLE layout and put that layout inside ScrollView. It should be working

Comment: scrollview should contain only one layout.. and that layout can have multiple child layouts.. so check if you're having more than one layout inside scrollview

Answer (score 1):

here is the simplest solution i found:

```html
ScrollView:
  GridLayout:
        id: glayout
        cols: 1
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
          text:"button1"
        Button:
          text:"button2"
        Button:
          text:"button3"
    
  #Put content that you need in gridlayout
```

Comment: Nisarg, this is what ManishNegi suggested (ie that you use one single layout in the ScrollView). You should accept their answer. Also, the other important point is that you bind the height of the layout to the minimum_height property as you have done in your code above.